# Clarifications about unsigned type in C

Tags: c, memory, char, unsigned, integer-promotion

Hi I'm currently learning C and there's something that I quite don't understand.
First of all I was told that if I did this:

```
unsigned int c2 = -1;
printf("c2 = %u\n", c2);
```

It would output 255, according to this table:

[image: table]

But I get a weird result: `c2 = 4294967295`

Now what's weirder is that this works:

```
unsigned char c2 = -1;
printf("c2 = %d\n", c2);
```

But I don't understand because since a `char` is, well, a `char` why does it even print anything? Since the specifier here is `%d` and not `%u` as it should be for unsigned types.

Comment: In C a `char` is also a numeric type

Comment: `int` (and also `unsigned int`) is usually a ***32*** bit integer type. The table you reference only shows *8* bits. Try to extrapolate the pattern using more bits...

Comment: Continue that table for 24 more bits and you have your answer

Comment: I know it's an integral type but isn't %d only for integers ?

Comment: Regarding that `%d` works for `char`, it's because values of type smaller than `int` are [*promoted*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Integer_promotions) to `int`.

Comment: I don't want -1 to be the output

Comment: Your table is for 8-bit representations. I doubt an `unsigned int` has an 8-bit representation on your platform.

Comment: int in C must contain at least 16 bits, not 8

Comment: @chux I was looking at the first `printf`. I should have deleted that comment earlier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this declaration

```
unsigned char c2 = -1;
```

the internal representation of -1 is truncated to one byte and interpreted as unsigned char. That is all bits of the object c2 are set.

In this call

```
printf("c2 = %d\n", c2);
```

the argument that has the type unsigned char is promoted to the type `int`  preserving its value that is 255. This value is outputted as an integer.

Is this declaration

```
unsigned int c2 = -1;
```

there is no truncation. The integer value -1 that usually occupies 4 bytes (according to the size of the type int) is interpreted as an unsigned value with all bits set.

So in this call

```
printf("c2 = %u\n", c2);
```

there is outputted the maximum value of the type unsigned int. It is the maximum value because all bits in the internal representation are set. The conversion from signed integer type to a larger unsigned integer type preserve the sign propagating it to the width of the unsigned integer object.

Comment: "the internal representation of -1 is truncated to one byte and interpreted as unsigned char.' --> A reasonable explanation for 2's complement `int`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code:

```
unsigned int c2 = -1;
printf("c2 = %u\n", c2);
```

Will never print `255`. The table you are looking at is referring to an unsigned integer of 8 bits. An `int` in C needs to be at least 16 bits in order to comply with the C standard (`UINT_MAX` defined as 2^16-1 in paragraph §5.2.4.2.1, page 22 [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf)). Therefore the value you will see is going to be a much larger number than 255. The most common implementations use 32 bits for an `int`, and in that case you'll see 4294967295 (2^32 - 1).

You can check how many bits are used for any kind of variable on your system by doing `sizeof(type_or_variable) * CHAR_BIT` (`CHAR_BIT` is defined in `limits.h` and represents the number of bits per byte, which is again most of the times 8).

The correct code to obtain `255` as output is:

```
unsigned char c = -1;
printf("c = %hhu\n", c);
```

Where the `hh` prefix specifier means (from [`man 3 printf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)):

> **hh**: A following integer conversion corresponds to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument, or a following `n`  conversion corresponds to a pointer to a `signed char` argument.

Anything else is just implementation defined or even worse *undefined* behavior.

Answer (score 0):

In C integer can have multiple representations, so multiple storage sizes and value ranges 
refer to the table below for more details.

[image]

Comment: The table you show (and which can't be copy-pasted from, or used by screen readers, please don't post images) are the most common ranges and sizes. Except for `long`, which could be 4 bytes (32 bits) even on a 64-bit system (e.g. Micosoft Visual C++ uses 32-bit `long`). And it misses the 64-bit (at *least*) type `long long`.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and the table is just showing *some* of the many valid implementations of the standard.